# Android Studio coverage tool says that project is out of date

Tags: android, android-studio, unit-testing

I am writing to unit test my Android app and see coverage results, but whenever I click on `Run with coverage`, after passing the tests, I get a pop up saying that the project is out of date and I need to recompile or hide coverage. When I recompile, I get some errors in the `Hilt` auto-generated classes (but there actually aren't any compilation errors because if I rebuild the project normally it works).

The tool is generating the coverage percentage but I cannot see the typical green or red sectors saying which parts are missing coverage. And the error is annoying. I tried rebuilding, cleaning, restarting caches, etc.

Is this a problem with `Hilt`? With `dataBinding` maybe?

Comment: Did you get any resolution on this?

Comment: I opened an issue in JetBrains tracker, but they seem aware of the issue and working on it. I guess we have to wait.

Comment: @anon37894203 can you plz share the ticket link?

Comment: Here you go: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/241258667